# plotting numerical values in a matrix on map

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix (TR5) of 40 x 100 dimensions having some  numeric data. I want to plot this data on the map of russia having limits as of latitude 40-80 degree and longitude 50-150 degree. Can anyone help me??
I am using meshm (Z,R,gratsize,TR5). I have assign gratsize as [40 100] and the result is not obtained as required...

Comment: A bit of a code example could be of help. Besides, what kind of plot do you want? E.g. something like an colour-coded "elevation" plot ... ?

Comment: @ernestopheles here is the code...TR4 (for required lat and long limit)is the selected value from parameter TR3(value for complete world)...i want a plot which is colour-coded as per the value in TR5(which is numeric such as -0.0031,5.8200)....Z = russia.map;TR4 = TR3(C);
Tr4 = cat(1,TR4,zeros(139,1));
TR5 = reshape(Tr4,40,100);gratsize = [40 100];
R = georasterref('RasterSize', size(Z), ...
    'latlim',[40 80], 'lonlim', [50 150]);worldmap(Z,R)
meshm(Z,R,gratsize,TR5)

Comment: 1) Could you please edit your initial question and insert the code in a way, it theoretically could be debugged? 2) "georasterref" is part of the mapping toolbox - kind of useful information, as very few people have installed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
load coast;
figure;
iptsetpref('ImshowAxesVisible', 'on');
imagesc([50 150], [40 80], TR5);
colormap(jet(256)); colorbar;
axis normal; set(gca, 'YDir', 'normal'); hold on;
plot(long, lat, 'color', [1 0 0]);
axis([50 150 40 80]); 
axis off; % EDIT
% set(gca, 'XTick', 50:10:150); % EDIT
% set(gca, 'YTick', 40:10:80); % EDIT
% xlabel('long in deg'); % EDIT
% ylabel('lat in deg'); % EDIT
hold off;
```

This should work without worldmap, though the map projection is not perfect. Substitute the Matlab-implemented "coast" (lat, long) by whatever your map is.

EDIT ... the source, based on your comment / request without axis.

Comment: actually the problem is the output should not be showing axis..it should show the area(projection system)..the code suggested by you is showing axes..i hope you understand what i am trying to tell..

Comment: Edited accordingly, no more axis. Well, in this example, the projection remains the same, plain and simple: The longitude becomes x and the latitude becomes y in a Cartesian coordinate system.